# Replacing variables in Terraform's 'templatefile' function without throwing errors

Tags: terraform

Terraform function 'templatefile' throw an error.

```
Invalid
│ character; Single quotes are not valid. Use double quotes (") to enclose
│ strings., and 89 other diagnostic(s).
```

But I have to leave it as it is, because it is a file that should have this format, because it is used by another framework.

For testing purposes I have replaced the `'` with `"`, but then another error was thrown:

```
There is no function named "VAL"., and 87 other
│ diagnostic(s).
```

How can I deal with it?

```
...
"key": "${VAL('Key.A')} - ${VAL('Key.B')}",
...
"another_key": "${var_to_replace}"
...
```

I want to only replace the `var_to_replace` with the `templatefile` function. If there is no corresponding variable in the vars parameter, then leave as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean you want to keep the raw as is value of `"${VAL('Key.A')} - ${VAL('Key.B')}"` and not template or substitute this line. you can use the double dolar syntax as detailed in [escape sequences](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#escape-sequences-1)

> Sequence   Replacement
> $${ Literal ${, without beginning an interpolation sequence.

**Template file**

```
"key": "$${VAL('Key.A')} - $${VAL('Key.B')}",
...
"another_key": "${var_to_replace}"
```

**terraform file**

```
output "example" {
  value = templatefile("main.tplf", {var_to_replace = "anotherval"})
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
example = <<EOT
"key": "${VAL('Key.A')} - ${VAL('Key.B')}",
...
"another_key": "anotherval"
EOT
```